# Custom Python location during Julia compilation

Tags: python, compilation, julia

I compile Julia from the source code. I have a newer version (3.6.3) of Python installed than the one which comes with my OS (2.7.5). The newer Python version is in my `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but the older version of Python is detected during Julia compilation:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found version "2.7.5")
```

How can force `make` to use Python version in a specific location during Julia compilation?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure it matters? I have a hunch Python is just used to run some installation scripts, but what comes out is Julia, which doesn't depend on Python. My guess is that the scripts are written with the intention of using the system Python, which is usually 2.7. I don't know though, just a thought.

Comment: @Engineero No, I am not sure if it matters. I am new to Julia. Thank you for your reply, though! If it does not matter, I do not need to worry about it. I did have to set an environment variable with a path to the Python installation to use with PyCall.jl. This is an indication that you might be right.